# VIM wrap block in curly braces (CSS code)

Tags: vim

kind of new to VIM so be kind please.

I want to do the following:

```
.css-class {
    some: 'rule';
}
```

to:

```
.another-class {
    .css-class {
        some: 'rule';
    }
}
```

I tried surround.vim with S{ in visual mode with the block selected. But this ends up here:

```
{ .css-class {
   some: 'rule';
} }
```

which doesn't really help much. If it would add the line breaks it would help but still... What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Visual-line mode, `V`, instead of `v`.

```
VipSB.another-class
```

You can also use the `yS` operator if you do not want to use visual mode:

```
ySipBi.another-class
```